# Proxy or VPN behind the router

Tags: fedora, vpn, openvpn, squid

I have a home network under the router, and there is my proxy server with ports forwarded through the router. Some clients connects to the Internet via my proxy, but there is a little problem - sometimes they cannot send files on email or html form (I'm using Squid as a proxy).

So, I've tryed to set up PPTP VPN with PoPTop, but connection through my router causes 619 error.

Server has Fedora 16. What is the best way to provide Internet connection to clients (VPN, another proxy configuration or something else)?

Comment: Was HTTPS activated in the proxy? What kind of error did they get when sending files?

Comment: No, there is no HTTPS. I dont know exactly what is the error - it is not in squid logs, but user cannot upload any file to server (e. g. image to Imgur)